# RegexField is not passing validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

As a part of my form I'm using a **RegexField** with the regex pattern **r'^\d{3}'**. Once the form is submitted, I'm getting a *KeyError* when `security_code = cleaned_data['security']` is reached.

I understand that once a form's *is_valid()* method is called, the *cleaned_data* dictionary only retains those key/values that pass validation. I'm not understanding however why a user supplied string to this form field is not passing validation in this case.

If I switch the RegexField to a CharField, then data for both fields appears in the cleaned data.

```
from django import forms

class CreditCardForm(forms.Form):
    cc_number = forms.CharField()
    security = forms.RegexField(r'^\d{3}', max_length=3)

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        card_number = cleaned_data['cc_number']
        security_code = cleaned_data['security']

        if card_number and security_code:
            if card_number.startswith('4') and len(security_code) != 3:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credit card information")
```

```
class CommentPage(View):
    def get(self, request):
        cc_form = CreditCardForm()
        return render(request, 'member_access/access.html', {'form' : cc_form})

    def post(self, request):

        submitted_cc_form = CreditCardForm(request.POST)

        if submitted_cc_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Submission successful!")
        return HttpResponse(reverse('member_access:user_login'))
```

Comment: Use `cleaned_data.get('security')`, this will return `None` when the field has not passed validation. If the form is not valid you should re-render the form with the errors

Comment: What is the value being submitted that is not passing validation?

Comment: don’t some credit cards have 4 digit security codes

Comment: `clean()` is a catchall function that is called _after_ the individual fields have been validated.  If any fields failed validation, they will not be available inside `clean()`.

Comment: I'm entering digits (ie. 1, 84, etc). So is the regex argument supplied the validator against the string supplied in the form?

Comment: Your regex only accepts strings of __exactly__ 3 digits - `{3}`. You can change this to accept 1 to 3 digits with `{1,3}`

Comment: That works now @IainShelvington. Thank you.